# How to hide a turtle icon/pointer in Python

Tags: python, visibility, turtle-graphics

When using Python `Turtle`, how do you hide turtle icon(s)/pointer(s) in turtle graphics in `Turtle` code so that it won't show when testing?

Answer (score 21):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html) has a section on [Visibility](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#visibility):

> `turtle.hideturtle()`
>   `turtle.ht()`
>   Make the turtle invisible. It’s a good idea to do this while you’re in the middle of doing some complex drawing, because hiding the turtle speeds up the drawing observably.

```
>>> turtle.hideturtle()
```

Also, you can un-hide the turtle:

> `turtle.showturtle()`
>   `turtle.st()`
>   Make the turtle visible.

```
>>> turtle.showturtle()
```

You can also query its visibilty:

> `turtle.isvisible()`
>   Return `True` if the Turtle is shown, `False` if it’s hidden.

```
>>> turtle.hideturtle()
>>> turtle.isvisible()
False
>>> turtle.showturtle()
>>> turtle.isvisible()
True
```

Answer (score 7):

One more practical method that the other answer failed to address is to set the `visible` keyword argument to `False` when defining the `Turtle` object:

```
import turtle

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
```

Of course, that is for when you want the `Turtle` to be invisible from the very beginning of the program.

When you define a `Turtle` object without setting `visible` to `False`, there will always be a lightning short moment where the turtle is still visible:

---

```
import turtle

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
# The Turtle may be visible before the program reaches the line under, depending on the speed of your computer 
my_turtle.hideturtle()
```

With the `visible` keyword argument set to `False`, you can always call `my_turtle.showturtle()` and `my_turtle.hideturtle()` in your code where ever the `Turtle` needs to be visible and hidden again.

---

Here are all the default `turtle` settings that you can customize *(the settings of interest here are the ones commented with the `# RawTurtle`)*:

```
_CFG = {"width" : 0.5,               # Screen
        "height" : 0.75,
        "canvwidth" : 400,
        "canvheight": 300,
        "leftright": None,
        "topbottom": None,
        "mode": "standard",          # TurtleScreen
        "colormode": 1.0,
        "delay": 10,
        "undobuffersize": 1000,      # RawTurtle
        "shape": "classic",
        "pencolor" : "black",
        "fillcolor" : "black",
        "resizemode" : "noresize",
        "visible" : True,
        "language": "english",        # docstrings
        "exampleturtle": "turtle",
        "examplescreen": "screen",
        "title": "Python Turtle Graphics",
        "using_IDLE": False
       }
```

---

*Update: I just noticed that cdlane's comment on the other answer pointed out this method, but comments are temporary.*