# How do i hide mouse pointer in turtle? (python)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Hello i am trying to make paint in python using turtle,pyautogui,win32api
And i was needed to hide mouse pointer but i didnt find hide mouse pointer function in turtle docs

I was trying to find anwser but theres was no anwser..
Is there a function to hide mouse pointer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide a turtle icon/pointer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804572/how-to-hide-a-turtle-icon-pointer-in-python)

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I think that's referring to hiding the turtle, while this question is about hiding the mouse pointer on Windows.

Comment: No. I am not trying to hide turtle

Comment: Can you show us what you're trying to achieve? Screenshot or something.